# Bootstrap data-toggle="button" not working with <span>

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, button

I'm using the 'data-toggle'-option from Bootstrap for a button. In the button I have a  with glypicons and sometext. However, when you click on the text it works, but when you click on the glyphicon it doesn't trigger the data-toggle.
Since the data-toggle does not work in JSFiddle I cannot post a link to it.

HTML:

```
<button type="button" id="showHide" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span> show</button>
```

JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById("showHide").onclick = function () {
    if ($("#showHide").text() == " show") {
        document.getElementById("showHide").innerHTML = "<span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-eye-close\"></span> hide";
        document.getElementById("showHide").blur();
    } else {
        document.getElementById("showHide").innerHTML = "<span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open\"></span> show";
        document.getElementById("showHide").blur();
    }
}
```

I've looked online but haven't found a solution or someone with the same problem.

Comment: Seems to work in this jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5qe31kw0/1/

Could you post a link to your code or re-create it in another jsfiddle?

Comment: @Brammz, I have provided a JSFiddle that looks like it provides the solution. What do you think? is that what you are after?

Comment: @Brammz, I remove the solution as I agree with Antfish, it appears that this is already working

Comment: @Antfish, thank you for the JSFiddle, when I tried it, I couldn't get it to work, but when you click the icon, the data-toggle does not go off

Comment: @Brammz What do you mean by "the data-toggle does not go off" ?

If you mean that the attribute is not removed then there is nothing in your code to remove it. I just managed to remove the attribute and it still works: https://jsfiddle.net/5qe31kw0/2/

I imagine it is a bootstrap hook for something.

Comment: @Antfish I mean that when the button text says "hide" the button itself is not toggled on. But the answer from Derek S works for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears the span is being replaced before the toggle event is propogated. You can use the `button` method to activate the toggle rather than the data attribute.

```
<button type="button" id="showHide" class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span> show</button>

document.getElementById("showHide").onclick = function () {
    if ($("#showHide").text() == " show") {
        document.getElementById("showHide").innerHTML = "<span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-eye-close\"></span> hide";
        jQuery("#showHide").button('toggle');        
        document.getElementById("showHide").blur();
    } else {
        document.getElementById("showHide").innerHTML = "<span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open\"></span> show";
        jQuery("#showHide").button('toggle');        
        document.getElementById("showHide").blur();
    }
}
```

[View Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/11199/)